# Using logic Iterator for Getting Attendence from datebase In caleder table

Tags: jquery, jsp, plsql, struts-1, struts1

I am  using `Struct Logic:Iterator` to show the calender date. Suppose an employees joining date is 1st of any month, that shows me the correct date. But if the employee joins on 2nd or any other date that mismatches the day & date is showing previous date as empty

here is snap image for the calender look at frontend 
[image]

```
<logic:iterate id="element" name="patten" scope="request" indexId="row">
    <%if((row.intValue())%7==0){%>
    <logic:equal name="element" property="attend1" value="A">
        <td class="absent" align="center" width="28" height="25""
            title="  <bean:write name="element" property="description1"/>"> 
            <bean:write name="element" property="pday"/> 
        </td>
    </logic:equal>
    <logic:equal name="element" property="attend1" value="P">
        <td class="present" align="center" width="28" height="25"
            title="<bean:write name="element" property="description1"/>"> 
            <bean:write name="element" property="pday"/> 
        </td>
    </logic:equal>
    <%if(((row.intValue())+1)%7==0){%>
</logic:iterate>
```

1. If I enter `joining_date` as 2nd or any mid day of month. If date is 2-nov-15 it shows sunday but it should be monday and at same time, sunday shows to me as blank block at the end of same row.
2. In the backend table we have a table as employee record, containg the joining date.

**Any help Thanks in advance?**

Comment: I above octuber calender snap is their I inserted joining date in backend table 3-oct-2015 On 3 -oct day is Saturday but it show me on Thrusday  &  1 & 2 showing me blank at the end of the row...

Comment: struts1 is deprecated, and it has nothing to do with struts2. Consider migrating to 2.3.24.1. As a suggestion, try putting more efforts in your question's grammar and formatting

Comment: Do I have any another option for this tag